# Best way to draw text in MonoGame without using a SpriteFont?

Tags: c#, performance, text, fonts, monogame

Alright, so I'm working on a game in MonoGame which is set in a computer operating system. As expected, it does a lot of text rendering. The in-game OS allows users to customize almost every aspect of the operating system - people have made skins for the OS that make it look like Mac OS Sierra, almost every najor Windows release since 95, Xubuntu, Ubuntu, and way more.

This game used to be written in Windows Forms however there are features I want to implement that simply are not possible in WinForms. So, we decided to move from WinForms to MonoGame, and we are faced with one huge problem.

The skin format we've made allows the user to select any font installed on their computer to use for various elements like titlebar text, main UI text, terminal text etc. This was fine in WinForms because we could use `System.Drawing` to render text and that allows the use of any TrueType font on the system. If it can be loaded into a `System.Drawing.Font`, it can be rendered.

But, MonoGame uses a different technology for rendering text on-screen. `SpriteFont` objects. The problem is, there seems to be no way at all to dynamically generate a `SpriteFont` from the same data used to generate `System.Drawing.Font`s (family, size, style, etc) in code.

So, since I seemingly can't create SpriteFonts dynamically, in my graphics helper class (which deals with drawing textures etc onto the current graphics device without needing copy-pasted code everywhere), I have my own DrawString and MeasureString methods which use System.Drawing.Graphics to composite text onto a bitmap and use that bitmap as a texture to draw onto the screen.

And, here's my code for doing exactly that.

```
public Vector2 MeasureString(string text, System.Drawing.Font font, int wrapWidth = int.MaxValue)
{
    using(var gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1)))
    {
        var s = gfx.SmartMeasureString(text, font, wrapWidth); //SmartMeasureString is an extension method I made for System.Drawing.Graphics which applies text rendering hints and formatting rules that I need to make text rendering and measurement accurate and usable without copy-pasting the same code.
        return new Vector2((float)Math.Ceiling(s.Width), (float)Math.Ceiling(s.Height)); //Better to round up the values returned by SmartMeasureString - it's just easier math-wise to deal with whole numbers
    }
}

public void DrawString(string text, int x, int y, Color color, System.Drawing.Font font, int wrapWidth = 0)
{
    x += _startx; 
    y += _starty;
    //_startx and _starty are used for making sure coordinates are relative to the clip bounds of the current context
    Vector2 measure;
    if (wrapWidth == 0)
        measure = MeasureString(text, font);
    else
        measure = MeasureString(text, font, wrapWidth);
    using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)measure.X, (int)measure.Y))
    {
        using (var gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            var textformat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            textformat.FormatFlags = System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
            textformat.Trimming = System.Drawing.StringTrimming.None;
            textformat.FormatFlags |= System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.NoClip; //without this, text gets cut off near the right edge of the string bounds

            gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel; //Anything but this and performance takes a dive.
            gfx.DrawString(text, font, new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B)), 0, 0, textformat);
        }
        var lck = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); //Lock the bitmap in memory and give us the ability to extract data from it so we can load it into a Texture2D
        var data = new byte[Math.Abs(lck.Stride) * lck.Height]; //destination array for bitmap data, source for texture data
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(lck.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length); //cool, data's in the destination array
        bmp.UnlockBits(lck); //Unlock the bits. We don't need 'em.
        using (var tex2 = new Texture2D(_graphicsDevice, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 4)
            {
                byte r = data[i];
                byte b = data[i + 2];
                data[i] = b;
                data[i + 2] = r;
            } //This code swaps the red and blue values of each pixel in the bitmap so that they are arranged as BGRA. If we don't do this, we get weird rendering glitches where red text is blue etc.

            tex2.SetData<byte>(data); //Load the data into the texture
            _spritebatch.Draw(tex2, new Rectangle(x, y, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), Color.White); //...and draw it!
        }
    }
}
```

I'm already caching heaps of textures created dynamically - window buffers for in-game programs, skin textures, etc, so those don't hit the performance hard if at all, but this text rendering code hits it hard. I have trouble even getting the game above 29 FPS!

So, is there a better way of doing text rendering without SpriteFonts, and if not, is there any way at all to create a spritefont dynamically in code simply by specifying a font family, font size and style (bold, italic, strikeout etc)?

I'd say I'm intermediate with MonoGame now but I have a hard enough time getting RenderTargets to work - so if you want to answer this question please answer it as if you were talking to a kindergarten student.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and as this is a major hot-buttin' issue in my game's development team you may see yourself mentioned in the game's credits as a major help :P

Comment: It sounds like you've got quite a challenge ahead of you. I don't know the exact solution to your problem but if it helps you're welcome to borrow some code from the [MonoGame.Extended BitmapFont](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/tree/develop/Source/MonoGame.Extended/BitmapFonts) implementation.

Comment: Thanks man, I replace my font rendering code with yours, with usage of System.Drawing, and I believe its the much better font rendering in MonoGame, especially for Asian characters. MonoGame have a poor support for multi-bytes Unicode characters.

Comment: If this project is still relevant to you, it might be worth checking out a class I built for this exact issue, it uses GDI+ but in a totally different(more simple way) to yours giving almost no hit on the performance of your game: https://github.com/Zintom/BitmapTextRenderer

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom spritefont using `System.Drawing` and use this one. It is basically every character that can be used, stored in a Dictionary with the corresponding `Texture2D`.

When you want to draw a text, you just draw every char next to eachother.

This is still slow (because drawing text without vector graphics is always slow) but at least you do not have to parse everything every frame.

Just specify somewhere what characters can be used and import them. Dictionaries are very fast in C# when it comes to indexing, so this shouldn't be a problem at all.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: "drawing text without vector graphics is always slow" are you sure about that?

Comment: in the case of writing letters in an environment that cannot draw raw letters out of their fonts, yes, I am. Fonts are vectorgraphics so you can scale them as big as you want without any alaising, but most game engines parse font files into a textureset and create a quad for every letter. This is often slower due to the rapidly increasing number of individually drawn vertices which need to be batched. This - of course - depends on the amount of text you want to display on screen, but compared to a little math for each character which is size independent, textures have more overhead.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I modified the code so that it draws the text itself in white, then I use the SpriteBatch's color tinting feature to get the desired color. This cuts out that forloop where I convert the RGBA data from System.Drawing to BGRA for a Texture2D.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that I cache text when I draw it by storing the texture in a list along with the font, raw text and wrapwidth and when I go to render text I check the list for a matching cached texture and render that if I can find it instead of generating a whole new texture. This DRAMATICALLY cuts down on both CPU and RAM usage. I also clear the cache every 30 seconds so that stale caches are removed from RAM.

Comment: That's a very nice solution! How do you handle text which comes from userinput?

Comment: @MaxPlay I see where you're coming from but I think you're discounting the fact that even a vector graphics system still has to have a "draw" pass. It not just a "little math" to calculate the shape of the vector. After the vector is calculated it still needs to be converted into something the graphics card can actually render. In today's technology there's many factors in how this [actually happens](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/performance-of-vector-graphics-versus-bitmap-or-raster-graphics) but it's safe to say it's not as simple as saying one way is always better.